# redefining index column in sales db

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I'm stuck cleaning this sales database where data is collected from multiple sources and bill numbers are a mess yet they are the only column to refer multiple orders to the same bill, yet the use of different systems over time resulted in duplicated bill numbers.

to fix this I need to give a new number to the bill number cell where the dates are different, for instance, if I have a bill no 1 and on a date in 2019 and another bill with the same bill number but in 2018 I need to give it a different bill number.

sample of df:

```
       bill_no  item_ser                date                  item size   price
0         1       111 2018-12-15 15:09:50          Rockla Salad    R   39.00
1         1       111 2018-12-15 15:09:50          Rockla Salad    R   39.00
2         1       112 2018-12-15 15:10:16                   Tea    R    8.00
3         1       112 2018-12-15 15:10:16                   Tea    R    8.00
4         1       309 2019-02-21 10:02:24            Eggs Toast    R   35.00
5         1       309 2019-02-21 10:02:24            Eggs Toast    R   35.00
6         1         1 2020-07-20 12:38:16      Nody's Sfilatino    R   99.75
7         1         1 2020-07-20 12:38:16      Nody's Sfilatino    R   99.75
8         1      2715 2020-05-06 01:13:41  Basilico Buffalo - R    R  110.00
9         1      2715 2020-05-06 01:13:41  Basilico Buffalo - R    R  110.00
10        1      2716 2020-05-06 01:13:41   Timmy's Merguez - R    R  130.00
11        1      2716 2020-05-06 01:13:41   Timmy's Merguez - R    R  130.00
12        1      2717 2020-05-06 01:13:41            Funghi - R    R  105.00
13        1      2717 2020-05-06 01:13:41            Funghi - R    R  105.00
14        1      2718 2020-05-06 01:13:41          Extra Cheese    R   20.00
15        1      2718 2020-05-06 01:13:41          Extra Cheese    R   20.00
16        1         8 2020-07-05 16:27:37        Margherita - R    R   65.00
17        1         8 2020-07-05 16:27:37        Margherita - R    R   65.00
18        1         9 2020-07-05 16:27:39      Extra Vegetables    R   10.00
19        1         9 2020-07-05 16:27:39      Extra Vegetables    R   10.00
20        1        10 2020-07-05 16:27:40       Extra Mushrooms    R   20.00
21        1        10 2020-07-05 16:27:40       Extra Mushrooms    R   20.00
22        2        11 2020-07-05 16:36:31          Marinara - R    R   55.00
23        2        11 2020-07-05 16:36:31          Marinara - R    R   55.00
24        2        12 2020-07-05 16:36:38   Timmy's Merguez - R    R  130.00
25        2        12 2020-07-05 16:36:38   Timmy's Merguez - R    R  130.00
26        2        77 2018-12-15 16:25:19                   Can    R   12.00
27        2        77 2018-12-15 16:25:19                   Can    R   12.00
28        2        78 2018-12-15 16:25:34        Margherita - L    L   63.00
29        2        78 2018-12-15 16:25:34        Margherita - L    L   63.00
30        2        79 2018-12-15 16:25:40        Margherita - R    R   45.00
31        2        79 2018-12-15 16:25:40        Margherita - R    R   45.00
32        2     11172 2019-11-26 12:26:46        Margherita - L    L   75.00
33        2     11172 2019-11-26 12:26:46        Margherita - L    L   75.00
34        2         2 2020-07-20 12:38:32      Nody's Sfilatino    R   99.75
35        2         2 2020-07-20 12:38:32      Nody's Sfilatino    R   99.75
36        2      2719 2020-05-06 01:25:21  Basilico Buffalo - L    L  135.00
37        2      2719 2020-05-06 01:25:21  Basilico Buffalo - L    L  135.00
38        2      2720 2020-05-06 01:25:21        Gamberetti - L    L  175.00
39        2      2720 2020-05-06 01:25:21        Gamberetti - L    L  175.00
40        2      2721 2020-05-06 01:25:21          Marinara - L    L   70.00
41        2      2721 2020-05-06 01:25:21          Marinara - L    L   70.00
42        2      2722 2020-05-06 01:25:21          Marinara - L    L   70.00
43        2      2722 2020-05-06 01:25:21          Marinara - L    L   70.00
44        2      2723 2020-05-06 01:25:21            Flat White    R   35.00
45        2      2723 2020-05-06 01:25:21            Flat White    R   35.00
46        2      2724 2020-05-06 01:25:21            Flat White    R   35.00
47        2      2724 2020-05-06 01:25:21            Flat White    R   35.00
48        2      2725 2020-05-06 01:25:21           Banana Milk    R   40.00
49        2      2725 2020-05-06 01:25:21           Banana Milk    R   40.00
```

I Tried for loop yet with 150K rows it takes a lot of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Get new_bill_no on the basis of [bill_no, date]
df1 = df[['bill_no', 'date']].drop_duplicates().reset_index()
df1.rename({'index': 'new_bill_no'}, axis=1, inplace=True)

# On Merging you will get new_bill_no in original df
df = df.merge(df1, on=['bill_no', 'date'], how='left'])
```

Comment: This Works great yet as date has time in it I need to aggregate on just the date ignoring at least minutes and seconds as some orders take more than a few minutes to register

Comment: Do you want to ignore `minutes` and `seconds` and keep `hour` and `date`?

Comment: I don't think it matters alot maybe I should just create an extra column with just dates with no timestamp and aggregate over that. will that work fine?

Comment: Yeah it will work fine..if you have unique `bill_no` for each `date`. And if in each `date`, there can be multiple `bills` with same `bill_no` then it is advisable to use dates with time.

Comment: pandas `merge_asof()` might be useful, to link timestamps that are close but not identical:  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html